# Regex match url pattern

Tags: regex

I already copied a regex expression from somewhere like this:

```
^(\*|http|https|file|ftp|ws|wss|data):\/\/(\*|(?:\*\.)?(?:[^*]+))?\/(.*)$
```

It can match URL patterns like `https://www.google.com/` or `https://*.google.com/`, I want to support to reach `https://www.google.*/`, how could I change the regex?

Comment: This is a weird pattern, the `[^*]+` part allows the "url" to contain [almost everything](https://regex101.com/r/VfYOFS/1), even whitespace (though requires a slash somewhere inside . I'd rather use something like [`^(?:https?|file|ftp|wss?|data):\/\/[^'"\s><]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/fqUCeh/2) but we don't know for what you are using this.

Comment: @bobblebubble Thanks, I want to match a match pattern as web extension: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns , but more, I want to support `https://www.google.*/` as a valid match pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\*|http|https|file|ftp|ws|wss|data):\/\/(\*|(?:\*\.)?(\*|(?:[^*]+)))?\/(.*)$
```

Comment: Thanks! but I want to match the  `www.google.*` as the 2nd group result, do you know how to do that?